# Why atom is not compiling my c++ program?

Tags: c++, compilation, atom-editor

I have written a program on 1st JAN 2023, and trying to run it in atom. But atom is not showing run option and even the sortcut f5 is not working.

I'm expecting the compilaion.

Comment: Likely related: [Sunsetting Atom](https://github.blog/2022-06-08-sunsetting-atom/)

Comment: [Stackoverflow cannot answer customer support questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745)